# Where did the Unity Market Insights button go in Unity Dashboard?

Tags: unity, analytics

I'm currently trying to find the Market Insights button in the Unity Dashboard. I'm following this youtube video by Code Monkey called "Make your Game Better with Unity Analytics!" where he shows how to connect a Unity project with the Unity dashboard.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jDD-E1OUkc&ab_channel=CodeMonkey (at 13:54)

Now, maybe it's because the video 2 years out of date, but I can't seem to find the market insights button. Is it still in the Unity dashboard? Has it been replaced with a new name? Or has it been removed entirely? If someone knows how to get there, please tell me how! Thank you!